# How to revert override browser.waitforAngular in protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I have a regression suite automated using Protractor & Jasmine. Application under test recently became hybrid application, bootstrapped with `NgUpgrade`.
after the upgrade, scripts are timing out in accessing some of the elements. I have added below script to override the `waitforAngular` function which is the fix for time out issue. However this will not work for login (non angular page)I need to revert this override for non-angular page. wondering if anyone can provide any help on this

```
**var script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
"angular.element(document.querySelector(\"body\")).injector()" +
".get(\"$browser\").notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback)";
browser.waitForAngular =  ()=> {
return browser.executeAsyncScript(script);
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

To override the default behaviour of Protractor to wait for Angular calls, you can disable the Angular wait by:
`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`

However, Protractor's Documentation recommends using wrapped driver directly instead of toggling the `waitForAngularEnabled` property which can lead to unstable script.

An alternative would be to use `browser.driver.<whatever>` instead of `browser.<whatever>`:

Example:

- `browser.get`            When the web page has Angular components
- `browser.driver.get` When the web page doesn't have Angular components

Comment: Tried 'browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)' but no luck.this.specStarted = function (result) {
  browser.executeScript("return !!(window.angular || window.ng);")
    .then(function(isAngular){
      if(isAngular) {
        var script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
          "angular.element(document.querySelector(\"body\")).injector()" +
          ".get(\"$browser\").notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback)"; browser.waitForAngular =  (test)=> { if(test){ return browser.executeAsyncScript(script);}}}
else {browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); } });};

Comment: added browser.driver.get too, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solution browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) in below on a non angular page but it is still going into browser.executeAsyncScript(script) and throwing error "angular not defined"

```
 this.specStarted = function (result) {
      browser.executeScript("return !!(window.angular || window.ng);")
        .then(function(isAngular){
          if(isAngular) {
            console.log('angular page ');
            var script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
              "angular.element(document.querySelector(\"body\")).injector()" +
              ".get(\"$browser\").notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback)";
            browser.waitForAngular =  (test)=> {
              if(test){
                return browser.executeAsyncScript(script);
              }
            }
          }
          else {
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
            console.log('not an angular page');
          }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be modifying default angularEnabled behaviour. By default, `waitForAngularEnabled` is `true`. You need to modify this by-default behaviour by using `waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. But keep in mind that it totally depands on the sequence of scripts running. i.e. If you are logged-in in app and now want to navigate to login page (non-angular page), You need to disable this by-default behaviour and whenever you enter another page i.e. Angular Page, You should enable its by-default behaviour.

Let me know if it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, this issue is resolved with the below code

```js
browser.waitForAngular = function(){var script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length -1]" +"angular.element(document.querySelector(\"body\")).injector()" +".get(\"$browser\").notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback)";
  if (!this.ignoreSynchronization) {
    return browser.executeAsyncScript(script);
  }
    else
  {
    return this.driver.controlFlow().execute(() => {
      return true;
    }, 
    'Ignore Synchronization Protractor.waitForAngular()')
  }
};
```